# Will I cause problem/cracks with jumping exercise in upper floor?

Tags: concrete, floor, safety, crack

Every day I am doing my martial art practice in upper floor. It contains jumping and power movements which cause sounds downstairs.

Is there any problem for concrete by this continuous jerking practice. If so please advise alternate solution. I have no place to practice on the lower floor.

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't be able to damage a concrete floor by jumping up and down on it.

There will be sound transmission (as you've noticed) and there *might* be some movement in the floor if it's not properly tied into the walls. This would be more likely with a wooden floor supported by joists as there is more natural movement in wood than concrete.

If there is movement this could cause the ceiling in the room below to show cracks in the plaster (assuming it is plastered) but these aren't structural and shouldn't worry you unduly. If cracks do appear then monitor them to see if they are growing or not. If they don't change length or width then you'll be able to fill them in and repaint. If they do change length or width then it could indicated that there is something amiss - usually something is loose, but this is unlikely with a concrete floor.